# Using Clash of Clans spells together

Tags: clash-of-clans

My query is about spells. Can a healing spell and a rage spell work together when dropped on a particular place? Will they work together or will the one dropped after will work? Has anyone tested it? Because I don't have a rage spell.

Comment: I'm assuming that this is about Clash of Clans, so I retagged the question.

Answer (score 6):

Spells that can affect your troops will only work together if they are **certain types**. 
 Rage spells that are deployed on top of each other **do not** have a cumulative effect.
According to the Clash of Clans Wikia article on [Spells](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Spells):

  "The Rage Spell's effects do not stack, even if multiple rage spells are used on the same location."
  "You can stack Healing Spells on top of each other to increase the effect."
  "The effects of the Jump Spell do not change if you drop more than one spell in the same area, so be careful not to use two in the same place!"

Answer (score 4):

All spells that affect troops in Clash of Clans work together when dropped at the same time, even if you drop more than 2 of a different kind.